# How to find the length of an array in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula `=SPLIT(E2,"/")` and I want to find the length of the array that the result returns.

I tried:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(SPLIT(E2,"/")))
=COUNT(SPLIT(E2,"/"))
=LEN(SPLIT(E2,"/"))
```

Comment: Counta should work - count only counts numbers - or  Columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try `COUNTA` as this one returns the number of values in a dataset, instead of `COUNT`:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(E2,"/"))
```

#### Reference

- [COUNTA Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991).

Answer (score 2):

```
=COLUMNS(SPLIT(E2,"/"))
```